# List node package dependencies without devDependencies

Tags: node.js, npm, dependency-management

I'd like to get a list of all external dependencies of my node.js project that is modules required by my project and modules required by those modules.  I tried two approaches,

- Tools that do a static code analysis (madge, require-analyzer, module-grapher).  But they don't do it recursively, visiting the required modules in the `node_modules` directory.
- Tools that get the information from `package.json`.  Well, not really tools, it means a plain `npm ls` invocations only.

The problem with the second approach is that is lists packages specified as `devDependencies`, too.  I realized I'd be happy to run `npm ls --no-dev` or something like that.  I tried `npm ls --production`, but it doesn't make any difference.  Any idea how I can achieve it?

Comment: I updated my question: modules required by my module

Comment: Yes, I want something along the line of `npm ls`, but production dependencies only

Comment: `--production` has been deprecated. Now it's `npm ls --only=production`

Comment: I seems not to be deprecated: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ls

Answer (score 21):

I had to use:

```
npm ls --prod
```

and to only show the first level of the tree:

```
npm ls --prod --depth=0
```

Here are the docs: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ls

Answer (score 0):

I was in the same situation but I've found this link

http://ilee.co.uk/list-node-packages-wo-dependencies/

It seems to work for me.

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged as they can go stale, it is better to include the pertinent points in your answer here